# How to bind-mount a directory into running LXC container on the fly?

Tags: mount, lxc

IOW — w/o getting those changes made theirs way through config file and container's restart — just to mount temporarily and w/o service interrupting.

Answer (score 3):

LXD (installed in Ubuntu 16.04) now includes a nifty feature allowing you to create "devices" and mount them into containers.

`lxc config device add <container name> <something share name> disk source=<path on host> path=<path on guest>`

For example,

On "host machine"

```
mkdir -p /shared/to/guest
echo "hello" > /shared/to/guest/test.txt
lxc config device add testcontainer sharetest disk source=/shared/to/guest path=/shared
```

Login to "guest container" and see `cat /shared/test.txt` ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but `LXD` is only a part of picture. Lots of LXCs are still in wild use w/o it.

Comment: What I'm pretty sure, it should be a simple mount-command w/o any LXD, you only need to know correct mountpoint probably.